# Empty matrix object after checking for a block type

Tags: craft3, matrix

Not sure if this is a bug or my logic is off. I'm trying to add caching logic to templates to not cache certain pages if they have a block type `form` present because of the dynamic `CSRF` tokens.

The logic:

```
{% set doNotCache = entry.mainBody.type('form').all()|length or craft.retour.getHttpStatus != 200 ? true : false %}
```

If the page returns `true`, the page renders properly. If the logic returns `false` the `entry.mainBody` object is empty (ie. doesn't render the matrix content). If I remove the logic all together the pages render properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there are some changes to how `.type()` works in Craft 3 which you can read about [here](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/changes-in-craft-3.html#cloning-element-queries). What's happening is the `type()` you're setting here in your `doNotCache` is also getting applied later on in your template when you start actually looping over the blocks in `entry.mainBody`. There are two ways to solve this:

1. Reset the `type()` in your matrix block loop

   ```
   {% for block in entry.mainBody.type(null).all() %}
   ```
2. Clone the `mainBody` field before you manipulate it

   ```
   {% set doNotCache = clone(entry.mainBody).type('form').all()|length or craft.retour.getHttpStatus != 200 ? true : false %}
   ```

Comment: I appreciate the help Jalen. Always good to learn new "gotchas" on how Craft 3 handles the `.type()` parameter method. I'm using the second option cloning the matrix field